# Angular- detecting a change in scope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope

I have a service that grabs JSON data for me and hands it off to a controller:

### Service snippet:

```
...
getP2PKeywordData: function(global_m, global_y) {

      // Return the promise
      return $http({
                url: base_url + 'get/P2P/kwords/', 
                method: "GET",

                // Set the proper parameters
                params: { 
                  year: global_y,
                  month: global_m
                  }
              })
              .then(function(result) {

                  // Resolve the promise as the data
                  return result.data;
              },
              function(data) {
                  // Error handling
              });
    }
    ...
```

The controller successfully grabs the data, which I have tested with a `console.log` underneath the `$scope.d3Data = data;` line.

### Controller snippet:

```
myApp.controller('DownloadsCloudCtrl', ['$scope', 
                                        '$rootScope', 
                                        'requestService',
                                        '$cookieStore',
  function($scope, $rootScope, requestService, $cookieStore) {
  $rootScope.$on('updateDashboard', function(event, month, year) {
    updateDashboard(month, year);
  });

  var updateDashboard = function(month, year) {
    requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {
      $scope.d3Data = data;
    });
  };

  updateDashboard($cookieStore.get('month'), $cookieStore.get('year'));
}]);
```

The controller is hooked up to a `d3-cloud` directive (d3 word cloud) that actually appends the proper `svg` elements and draws the word cloud with the data.  **However, for some reason the controller above isn't passing the `$scope.d3Data` to the directive.**

This is confusing because when I hardcode in an array of data into the controller, something like this...

```
$scope.d3Data = [
    {
        'kword': 'a',
        'count': 20,
    },{
        'kword': 'b',
        'count': 10,
    ...
```

... it connects to the directive perfectly!

### Directive snippet:

```
myApp.directive('d3Cloud', ['$window', 
                            'd3Service', 
                            'd3Cloud', 
                            function($window, 
                                     d3Service, 
                                     d3Cloud) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      label: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
        window.onresize = function() {
          scope.$apply();
        };
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return angular.element($window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function() {
          scope.render(scope.data);
        });
        scope.render = function(data) {
```

### HTML snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="module">
      <div class="inner-module" ng-controller="DownloadsCloudCtrl">
        <div class="module-graph">
          <d3-cloud data="d3Data"></d3-cloud>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

## What have I tried:

1. I tried to add a manual `$scope.$apply()` after the `$scope.d3Data = data;` line in the controller.  This, oddly, worked the first time I did it, but on every page refresh after that I got a "`$digest` already in progress" error (which was to be expected...).
2. In order to fix the `$digest` error, I tried encapsulating my `$apply` function in a `$timeout` code chunk, and even the dreaded `$$phase` conditional.  Both of these solutions fixed the console error, but failed to solve the original problem of passing the data from the controller to the directive.

**TL;DR: I'm fairly lost.  Ideas on where to troubleshoot next?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are treating the response as a promise twice.  So once in the service:

```
  .then(function(result) {

      // Resolve the promise as the data
      return result.data;
  },
```

And in the controller you resolve the promise again:

```
requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {
  $scope.d3Data = data;
});
```

This can work because (from my understanding) Angular sometimes resolves promises automatically when binding to the scope.

It would be better to just handle the promise in the controller only.  So the service becomes:

```
getP2PKeywordData: function(global_m, global_y) {

      // Return the promise
      return $http({
                url: base_url + 'get/P2P/kwords/', 
                method: "GET",

                // Set the proper parameters
                params: { 
                  year: global_y,
                  month: global_m
                  }
              });
    }
```

UPDATE:

Try to initialize the `d3Data` scope property to an empty collection, and then push the response data into it.  For example:

```
myApp.controller('DownloadsCloudCtrl', ['$scope', 
                                        '$rootScope', 
                                        'requestService',
                                        '$cookieStore',
  function($scope, $rootScope, requestService, $cookieStore) {

  //added
  $scope.d3Data = [];      

  $rootScope.$on('updateDashboard', function(event, month, year) {
    updateDashboard(month, year);
  });

  var updateDashboard = function(month, year) {
    requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {

         //then
         angular.forEach(data, function(thing) {

             $scope.d3Data.push(thing);
         )};

    });
  };

  updateDashboard($cookieStore.get('month'), $cookieStore.get('year'));
}]);
```

Comment: That makes sense- I removed the promise in the service, nothing has changed though, no new errors, no nothing.  I hate debugging Angular... any more ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you are binding in the `d3Data` in markup?

Comment: Added the HTML!  Thanks a ton Davin.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but maybe you should initialize an empty collection in the controller, then push the resulting data into it.  Then the object reference will remain constant for the directive.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand... so you're suggesting to not add any additional `$apply` or `$timeout` or `$$phase` logic, and use a helper array to pass the `data` into?  Example code?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.  Yes, there should be no need for `$apply` in this case.  the `$http` calls are already inside a `$digest` cycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56359/discussion-between-zelliott-and-davin-tryon).

Comment: Sorry, can't right now as I'm on the move.  Hope I've helped a little, at least.